# How to redirect URL in CodeIgniter after form submission back to the previous page only when the user comes from that page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, codeigniter

I've tried several ways to redirect the URL back to the page where the user came from after submitting a form or just refresh the form page to allow the user to make a new entry if the user came directly to it. So far, I've been unsuccessful. The following method is the closest I've got but I'm not sure what's going wrong -

The user clicks this link which takes them to the page where the form is -

```
<a target="_blank" class="sampleredirect" href="<?php echo base_url();?>sample/controller/add">Add User</a>
```

Upon clicking, the following jQuery script links the click to a function -

```
<script>
$('#sampleredirect').click(function(){
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "sample/controller/redfunc",
   }).done(function( msg ) {
      alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   });
});
</script>
```

The function gets the URL where the click was initiated -

```
public function redfunc(){
        $referred_from = $this->session->set_userdata('referred_from',current_url());
        return $referred_from;
    }
```

Inside `sample/controller/add` where the form logic is located, after the submission, I'm calling the function to redirect the user back to the previous URL -

```
public function adduser(){
   //sample code
   $this->redfunc();
   redirect($referred_from, 'refresh');
}
```

This isn't working and I keep getting redirected to the default page that shows up if a URL can't be found. When I do `vardump($referred_from)` after calling the function `$this->redfunc();`, I'm getting `NULL`.

I'm kinda lost here and would love some help with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$referred_from` will return nothing. It is just setting a session. It will not return session value. Try below code

```
<script>
$('#sampleredirect').click(function(){
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "sample/controller/redfunc",
      data: {current_url:<?=current_url()?>}
   }).done(function( msg ) {
       alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   });
});

public function redfunc(){
    $this->session->set_userdata('referred_from',$this->input->post('current_url');
}

public function adduser(){
   //sample code
   $referred_from = $this->session->referred_from;
   redirect($referred_from, 'refresh');
}
```

Comment: @AnishSana: If my answer helped you please mark as right answer so other can take help from it.

Comment: Thanks, for the help. I'll be glad to mark yours as the right answer. Not sure if I was dreaming but it worked well initially and then stopped. It looks like the Ajax script isn't passing in the URL to the php function. Been trying to figure out why for the past 2 days. Do you see anything wrong in the ajax script?

Comment: I was using 'class' inside <a> and then '#' in my Ajax script. *facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the `$referred_from` in your `adduser` function.

```
$this->redfunc();
```

You need assign a variable there. Because you want to receive `result` from `redfunc()` right?

so, Try it.

```
 public function adduser(){
       //sample code
       $referred_from = $this->redfunc();
       redirect($referred_from, 'refresh');
    }
```

or you can do this

```
public function adduser(){
           //sample code
           redirect($this->redfunc(), 'refresh');
        }
```

sorry. bad english

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I somehow overlooked that. Although my main problem was how I was retrieving the session value, as corrected by @Vinie [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37477613/3906773).

Answer (score 0):

```
$referred_from = $this->session->userdata('referred_from');
```

use `session->userdata` to get current_url which you have stored in the session

**set url in session**

```
$this->session->set_userdata('referred_from',current_url());
```

**Retrieve from session**

```
 $this->session->userdata('referred_from');
```